# Error al correr aplicacion en AndroidStudio (aapt.exe'' finished with non- zero exit value 1)

Tags: android-studio

Antes no me salia este error, de un momento salio el error y no me deja correrlo en el celular para probarlo:

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Miguel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non- zero exit value 1

¿Cual es la solución a este error ? Gracias

Comment: Hola Miguel, en luggar de la imagen que a penas se nota, puedes colocar el texto del mensaje de error como texto? Además agrega mas información sobre tu entorno para que se pueda investigar el error

Comment: Hola Miguel, de un momento tienes ese error porque probablemente tienes alguna aplicación que esta consumiendo más memoria y la dedicada a Android Studio no es suficiente, reinicia porque no te dejara construir la aplicación, cambia el Heap Size, revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Dos opciones para este detalle :

> \aapt.exe'' **finished with non- zero exit value 1**

1) Realiza :

`Clean project` -> `Rebuild Project`

y reinicia, con eso puede ser suficiente pero seguramente tendrás el mismo problema recurrentemente, así que el punto dos sería el adecuado.

2) El error  `finished with non- zero exit value 1`, es regularmente asociado a problemas de memoria, así que puedes agregar `javaMaxHeapSize`y definir tu "heap size" dentro de tu `build.gradle` :

```
android {
............
dexOptions {
     ...
     ...
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g" 
}
```